# Detecting a patched version of OpenJDK

Tags: patch, java

I need to determine whether a user's version of OpenJDK is susceptible to a particular security vulnerability. As an example, CVE-2016-0695 was discovered in OpenJDK 8u77, as revealed in the [April 2016 Critical Patch Update](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/2948264.xml). Ideally, detecting whether a user's OpenJDK version is vulnerable would be as simple as checking whether it's `<= 8u77` or `> 8u77` and accordingly marking it as vulnerable or not (assuming that all previous versions are also vulnerable and that the fix gets applied by the next version). The picture gets muddied by manual patches, though.

If I understand correctly, the April 2016 patch would be automatically bundled into the next version of OpenJDK8 (8u91, in this case), but would also be available for manual application. The latter would probably be an attractive option to risk-averse users who want to keep their Java version as-is while patching security holes. If a user manually applies the patch to their 8u77 install, is there any way for me to detect that? For instance, does the version number reported by `java -version` change? Or is there no indicator that a patch had been applied?

Comment: Have you tried applying the patch and testing the version string?

Comment: I would have, but you need an Oracle support contract to access those (unless they're available elsewhere?).

Comment: @alex-poole , I included the [tag:oracle] tag since the security patches seem to be released/managed by Oracle and applied through their `opatch` utility, so I figured Oracle users could weigh in. Should I keep it out?

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Bit of a confusing tag name.

Comment: @sevko - yeah, it happens quite a lot *8-) Just re-read my previous comment and it sounded snarkier that it was supposed to. Don't think it adds anything now anyway so I'll remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OpenJDK build comes from a vendor, the vendor may publish security information.  For example, here is the [CVE-2016-0695 security information from Debian](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-0695).  This information typically contains the first fixed package version, according to some vendor-specific versioning scheme.

However, in general, you need to obtain the sources for that OpenJDK build and review them if they have to fix.

To find the patch corresponding to a particular CVE ID (say CVE-2016-0695), in most cases, the easiest way is to go to the Red Hat Bugzilla tracker, here [the flaw bug for CVE-2016-0695](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2016-0695), and note the internal Oracle bug number listed there, 8138593 in this case.  Then you need to check out the appropriate OpenJDK sub-tree, in this case for the `jdk` component:

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk
```

And look in the history for the appropriate commit, based on the Oracle bug number (8138593):

```
changeset:   11581:594e8dca337c
user:        igerasim
date:        Thu Dec 24 08:42:10 2015 +0300
summary:     8138593: Make DSA more fair
```

The commit themselves do not contain CVE IDs (which are often not available when the fix is written, so this is understandable), so the detour via the Red Hat bug tracker is needed.  (I have not seen a CVE-ID-to-bug-number mapping from Oracle.)

You can view the patch using another Mercurial command:

```
hg export 594e8dca337c
```

Once you have the patch, it is a matter of review the source code to check whether it has been applied.  If you cannot obtain the source code for some reason, for changes to the `jdk`, it is often sufficient to disassemble the relevant classes using `javap -c`.  For native code, you need a different disassembler (such as `objdump -dr`).

Comment: To add further to this. Applying a patch does not automatically change the build number.  Build numbers are an artifact of the OpenJDK build process where there are a number of flags you can set during the configure stage.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenJDK JDK 8 Updates Project provides source code, rather than builds or binary patches. Per the Q&A at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/qanda.html

> Security fixes for this Project's source code will be made available
>   in the JDK 8 Update Project around the same time as they're released
>   in products from Oracle

They are made available in order to be integrated into the Project's Mercurial forest. Such source code patches are ***not*** provided separately, to be applied manually by users for other releases.

In general, if you need to understand whether a particular change has been applied in a third party build, you will need to get and compare the source code from upstream and the third party builds and/or their commit history. Mechanisms to obtain the source code, commit history, patching policies, patch versioning and patch timing may differ from third party to third party.

Comment: I was under the impression that Oracle provided binary patches that you can apply with something like the `opatch` utility. Is that incorrect? If so, then the conclusion is that patches only exist in source code form, and so I only need to worry about them being applied at the JDK maintainer level (rather than at the end-user level, since they seldom build their own JDK from source), right?

Comment: Since Oracle doesn't provide executable binaries for individual OpenJDK 8 updates through the OpenJDK Community, there is no actual binary to patch there. Dalibor Topic Principal Product Manager Java Platform Group @ Oracle